Do alkoxides work as bases in the aryne mechanism?
I'm teaching a course, and when it came to nucleophilic aromatic substitution, some professors at my department started teaching undergrads that when you have a non-activated halobenzene, it undergoes a substitution via the aryne mechanism when you use an alkoxide (e.g. sodium methoxide). I only encountered examples of the aryne mechanism reactions with amides or even stronger bases, and alkoxides are obviously much weaker bases. I have always been under the impression that such reactions undergo a normal SnAr, albeit under harsher conditions.
So, my question is: are they simply wrong or am I missing something here? Any literature sources will be appreciated.
Update: I checked the literature. It appears that both I and the instrtuctors were kind of wrong in different ways. Such reactions either create a mess of side reactions or proceed via a mixture of SNAr and aryne mechanisms. That said, unactivated substrates can absolutely react via pure SNAr if other substrates and/or nucleophiles are involved.

Maybe in certain cases.

I found one example in a textbook [1], unfortunately, no primary literature is ever cited:
$$
\ce{PhBr} + \ce{KO^{t}Bu} \rightarrow \ce{KBr} + \ce{PhO^{t}Bu}
$$
in DMSO, which would solvatize the cation and leave the anion naked, thus more reactive.
They mention the elimination-addition mechanism with $\ce{NaNH2/NH3 (l)}$ and neat/fused $\ce{NaOH}$.

[1] Clayden, Greeves, Warren, Wothers: Organic Chemistry, Oxford University Press, 2001, p. 601.

A prmary reference[1] is given for a benzyne-type reaction with monohalogenated tropolones, specifically methoxide ion with the bromotropolone isomers. Observed products and spectroscopic data provide evidence for such an intermediate. Compared with a benzenoid ring, a tropolone ring may undergo benzyne-type formation more easily because:

the tropyl ring inherently builds a positive charge into its aromatic structure, expected to make removal of a proton easier;

the larger ring size allows slightly more favorable bond angles for the triple bond formation.


Reference

Tetsuo Yamatani, Masafumi Yasunami, Kahei Takase. "Dehydrotropolones: a benzyne-type intermediate in the reactions of halotropolones with alkoxides." Tetrahedron Letters 11, 20 (1970), 1725-1728.
ISSN 0040-4039, https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(01)98066-9.

